# Position of cursor in WKWebView with an editable paragraph in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, contenteditable, wkwebview

Is there anyway to get the position of the cursor in a `WKWebView` in iOS that contains an editable paragraph (a paragraph with attributed `contentEditable` set to true)?

EDIT: To add additional information, the editable div can contain other subnodes

Comment: Hello @markusian, have you find any way to solve this?

Comment: No, I did not manage unfortunately, but if I remember correctly, I used another method to reach my goal

Comment: There is no 'Cursor' method in iOS. Try getting the UIScrollView position of your webView which will tell you the 'Y' position and if zoomed will also produce an XY position

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to `document` and mouse position inside the view you can use `document.elementFromPoint(x, y);`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in multiple ways using HTML5 (using `autofocus` atribute) or using javascript (`document.getElementById("IDHERE").focus();` - using focus event). I will write all in one code snippet uncomment and use it based on your requirement.

```js
//if u commnet the second form 
let domObject =  document.getElementById("lname"); // refer which object to focus
domObject.focus(); // event to trigger focus on the refereced dom object  

//throw error till second form is uncommented
```

```html
<!-- html5 way the most easiest way -->

<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" autofocus><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<!-- autofocus refers where to focus -->
<!-- unncoment below and comment above -->
<!-- javascript way -->

<!-- 
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" id="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" id="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

-->
```